# Why don’t mobile browsers read image EXIF Orientation tags while desktop browsers do?

Tags: css, image, orientation, exif

I have a problem with this.

Please open this link: http://otsuki-kanko.info/blog/view/23997

If you do so on desktop browser (Google Chrome or Safari) then scroll until the middle of the page and you will see pictures orientation is correct.

If you then do this on mobile Google Chrome or Safari (iOS 11.2.5) you will see that a few photos in the middle of the page a turned left or right.

How to fix that? Is there only way to do this manually?

Thank you.